# extract two parts of a string using regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
  &lt;img src=images/imagename.gif alt='descriptive text here'&gt;
```

and I am trying to split it up into the following two strings (array of two strings, what ever, just broken up).

```
  imagename.gif
  descriptive text here
```

Note that yes, it's actually the `&lt;` and not `<`.  Same with the end of the string.

I know regex is the answer, but I'm not good enough at regex to know how to pull it off in PHP.

Comment: You can also use DOM xpath which is faster than regex

Comment: So speed is the only reason? or is there other reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$s="&lt;img src=images/imagename.gif alt='descriptive text here'&gt;";

preg_match("/^[^\/]+\/([^ ]+)[^']+'([^']+)/", $s, $a);

print_r($a);
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => &lt;img src=images/imagename.gif alt='descriptive text here
    [1] => imagename.gif
    [2] => descriptive text here
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use `DOM xpath rather than regex`

```
<?php
$your_string = html_entity_decode("&lt;img src=images/imagename.gif alt='descriptive text here'&gt;");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($your_string);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom); 

foreach($x->query("//img") as $node) 
{
    echo $node->getAttribute("src");
    echo $node->getAttribute("alt");
}

?>
```

Comment: why would this be better than the preg_replace solution?

Comment: The DOM tools are a little more flexible in terms of syntax.  With a regexp, your input data must be EXACTLY what you planned for when you wrote the regexp.  For example, if the input contained `alt='...'` before `src='...'`, then the regexp will fail, but DOM will still work.  But if you know that your input text will always follow a certain pattern, the regexp solution may use an imperceptibly smaller amount of CPU.